# css layout problem why doesn't a div with absolute positioning recognize an encapsulating td cell

Tags: css

I have the arrangement below.  My question is, why won't the first div tag align to the top of the cell, instead it moves down to the top of the image (both ie and firefox etc.)?  Absolute positioning will not work as it appears that the div will not recognize the td cell as its parent and instead moves to the top of the document.  Is there a way around this?

```
<td style="width:33%;height:100%; border:solid 1px black; position:relative;">

                        <div style="vertical-align:top;">test</div>

                        <div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;padding-bottom:120px; padding-top:30px;">
                            <img src="<%=LastThumb%>" style="vertical-align:middle; border:solid 1px black;" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Comment: Background: http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/68126

Comment: Yes, the trouble with that is that in IE the containing div does not, even with the height of all parent objects set to 100%, expand to fill the td and instead only expands it enough for the objects contained within it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `position:absolute;` will cause the element to be COMPLETELY REMOVED from the regular flow of the other elements and make the div (and its children) then relative to the document window itself instead of its parent.

You are also using <div> elements, which are *block-level* elements. Thus, the browser will always place only one per line separated by line-breaks. You can get around this by adding `display:inline-block;` to both of the divs' CSS styles. This will then cause both divs to be treated as *inline* elements, allowing you to place one "on top" of the other.